# Why is pressing = repeatedly on iPhone calculator useful?

Tags: ios, iphone

Press these keys on iPhone calculator:

5 + 5 =

Unsurprisingly, the answer is 10. But keep on pressing the = sign and this is the output:

10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45 … and so on

Why is this useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an **auto-constant**
Whether or not you find it useful depends on what you want to do.

Your method of just hitting `=` over & over just repeats the last calculation, so
 `2 * 2 =` 4 `=` 8 `=` 16 `=` 32 etc

But, say you needed to calculate tax on a set of payments at 15%

If you want just the tax, type
`100 * 0.15 =`
then your amounts
`87.20 =`  13.08
`43.57 =` 6.55
`12.50 =` 1.88 etc..
If you wanted the amount including tax, you'd start with
`100 * 1.15 =` & off you go with your amounts, as above...

From comments - this function has been on calculators [in slightly different ways] since at least the mid-70s. It's not a new feature.
On the early ones, `2*=======`... would quickly just `ERR`. Since then they've got somewhat more flexible & move to scientific notation.

Comment: I think it's important to note that this has been on calculators pretty much since the time they were digital.  I remember it being there in the early '80s.

Comment: For sure, it's been there a long time, my 70's LED Texas did it - though surprisingly not on all & not all work the same way round. I've known my tax example to need `0.15*100=` to kick it off.

Comment: My HP19B needed something to prime the pump as well.  Just found a video of a hack to the `=` button on a cheap calculator turning it into a counter:  https://youtu.be/VLAv7cNCB3U

Comment: Wow... does that guy need to employ a cameraman ;) but yeah, neat idea.